# Why does my browser keep redirecting to the index and not the views?

Tags: python, django

Working with **Python 2.7 and Django 1.1**.

Trying to get this code from the "Writing your first Django app" to work, I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

**polls\urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^<int:question_id>/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
        url(r'^<int:question_id>/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
        url(r'^<int:question_id>/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    ]
```

**mysite\urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Please let me know if I am missing any necessary code to provide context?

Comment: You should really move away from Django 1.x, it is not supported for some time now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In django 1.11, `url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),` matches any url that contains the regular expression `^` (ie the start of a string). Since any string contains a beginning this will match every string.

You can either move `'^'` to the end, so it will only match urls that do not match any other path, or use `'^$'`, (ie the start of a string immediately followed by the end of a string), to avoid matching paths you do not want to match.